# Transition from UIView to CCScene in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, objective-c

I've surfed the internet for quite some time but haven't come to find an answer.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am trying to perform a transition from a UIView to a CCScene
So i have a class which is connected to a .xib file.
I am able to present that scene using

> [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[LevelSelect scene]
>   withTransition:[CCTransition transitionCrossFadeWithDuration:1]];

But when i try to change to a CCScene which does not have a .xib file, it doesn't perform the transition, but plays the audio that is present in the next scene.

> [[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[Play
>   sceneWithDifficulty:1]];

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, i was adding the view but not removing it. 
So, even if the view was loading, it loaded under all the view.

Now before every transition, i remove the current xib view and then perform the transition.

> [myXIBFile removeFromSuperView];